# Lewis Carroll's deduction logic, is there one involving Engineers and Salesmen?

Tags: logical-deduction

50 years ago I was given some logical deduction questions apparently from a Lewis Carroll Anthology. I can no longer find them in an Anthology or in his Symbolic Logic Book. I used them on a computer Stephen Hawking was working on, but unfortunately, we are unable to ask the source.